# Hosting multiple websites dynamically in Azure web roles

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-deployment

We've got 3 or 4 services running on all sorts of hosting all over the place and I'm looking to consolidate using Azure. The traffic to the sites and services is currently low so it makes sense to host them all in one (2 instance) deployment. I know I could just host these all in a VM with IIS but I like the low maintenance of the web role platform.

I've seen how to do this by deploying them together in the same solution but with different teams working on each site it could get very complicated. I was looking for a host wep app which loads all the sub sites from source control but haven't found anything and I'm considering making something myself. I'd make an ASP MVC app that stored the deployments in a database and deployed them as required.

Is it possible to modify the sites hosted in a web role while its running? How do you set up the routes? Does replacing the deployed files cause the appdomain to recycle? Can most of this be achieved with `Microsoft.Web.Administration`? Any pitfalls that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to modify the sites in a webrole while its running?**
Yes if you RDP into it and change it. That would be instance specific though and would need to be repeated for each instance. Not recommended, but possible. Otherwise theres no other way.

**How do you setup the routes?**
No different than how you do it normally in IIS.

**Will the appdomain recycle if you change the site?**
If changes are to the binaries (/bin) yup. It's just regular IIS at play in a WebRole, no different.

**Any pitfalls:**
This sounds like an interesting idea and if you re putting it out on github/codeplex i'd be interested. Since I have not tried this so can't comment on the pitfalls.